# Pygame Move through a list of points?

Tags: python, math, path, pygame

I am trying to create a tower defense game, but I need the enemies to move on a path. I thought I had it figured out, but when I went to try out my code, it only worked *sometimes*.

Sometimes the enemy would go to the point it was supposed, sometimes it wouldn't. It works based off of a list of points that create the path, I made the enemy move through them, and when it reaches one point, it goes to the next.

I've tried many different tests to see if the player is in contact with the point, but none of them work consistently. The one in the code currently works the best, but not every-time. (

```
except ZeroDivisionError:
    bullet_vector=''
if bullet_vector==(0,0):
    bullet_vector=''
```

)

From what I can tell, I just need to find a better test for when the object is at the point where it is supposed to change directions. Here is the code:

```
import pygame,math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
run=True
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
def Move(t0,t1,psx,psy,speed):
    global mx
    global my

    speed = speed

    distance = [t0 - psx, t1 - psy]
    norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
    try:
        direction = [distance[0] / norm, distance[1 ] / norm]
        bullet_vector = [int(direction[0] * speed), int(direction[1] * speed)]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        bullet_vector=''
    if bullet_vector==(0,0):
        bullet_vector=''
    return bullet_vector

class AI(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.path=[(144,114),(280,114),(280,301),(74,300),(74,400)]
    def update(self):
        self.move_vector=Move((self.path[0])[0],(self.path[0])[1],self.x,self.y,1)
        if self.move_vector != '':
            self.x += self.move_vector[0]
            self.y += self.move_vector[1]
        else:
            self.path=self.path[1:]
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,((255,0,0)),(self.x,self.y),3,0)
enemies=[AI(-5,114)]
while run:
    screen.fill((0,200,0))
    for e in enemies:
        e.update()
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            run=False
    clock.tick(99)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

If someone can figure out where I went wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer my self, but it only supports four directional movement (which is what I need anyway) It even allows for adjustable speed! Here it is if anyone wants it:

```
import pygame,math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
run=True
themap=pygame.image.load('map1.png')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

class AI(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.path=[(144,114),(280,114),(280,300),(100,302)]
    def update(self):
        speed=2
        if self.x<(self.path[0])[0]:
            self.x+=speed
        if self.x>(self.path[0])[0]:
            self.x-=speed
        if self.y<(self.path[0])[1]:
            self.y+=speed
        if self.y>(self.path[0])[1]:
            self.y-=speed
        z=(self.x-(self.path[0])[0],self.y-(self.path[0])[1])
        if (z[0]/-speed,z[1]/-speed)==(0,0):
            self.path=self.path[1:]
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,((255,0,0)),(self.x,self.y),3,0)
enemies=[AI(-5,114)]
while run:
    screen.blit(themap,(0,0))
    for e in enemies:
        e.update()
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            run=False
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```